# "the dog I kicked" vs. "the dog that I kicked"

Tags: redundancy

Are both of the following correct? If so, when should each be used?

> The dog I kicked is sad.

> The dog **that** I kicked is sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. The relative pronoun "that" can be omitted when it is the object of the verb in the relative clause (the verb "kicked" in your example)

It is a matter of free choice whether you omit it or nor not.  Both forms are equally grammatical, equally natural, equally formal.